# one-class SVM for a parking application

Tags: scikit-learn, svm

I am using one-class SVM in scikit-learn to make some predictions on a parking application with 10 parking slots. An example of the features that I use is:hour, number of cars parked in slot 1, number of cars parked in slot 2, ..., number of cars parked in slot 10. 
Then, with the SVM what I want is to know if there is a problem with the system and there are some hours which globally the slots are receiving a not-normal number of cars. 
Hence, the feature 'hour' is important since some hours of the day the slots receive regularly more cars than other hours. So, what would be normal at 4h where there are almost no cars it is not normal at 18h.

I would like to train a single one-class SVM for this problem. However, since in most of the hours there are lots of cars parking then the hours with few cars are detected as outliers, instead of detecting when there is no coherence between the hour and the cars parked in the slots.

How should I train the one-class SVM? Should the hour be a feature? or should I train 24 one-class SVM for each hour?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: To figure out if "are some hours which globally the slots are receiving a not-normal number of cars" you would be better served with a graph. I also don't understand what you mean about determining "if there is a problem with the system."

Comment: I agree, start with some visualization of your data, before trying fancy outlier detection.

Comment: @Alex, what I try to achieve here is an automatic Intrusion Detection System. So, raising an alarm if the parking system is under an attack. I agree that a graph would serve with simple data. But if I use vectors with tens of features I need a machine learning algorithm.